# I can not see My android applicatio in google play from Samsung Galaxy s3

Tags: android

I uploaded my android application in google play. After uploading it on google play, I can't see the samsung galaxy s3 in the list of available devices.

I tried to find the answer everywhere but I can't solve it.

I also posted my android menifiest file below:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.eliteplatinum.budgetplanner"
  android:versionCode="12"
```

      android:versionName="2.1" >

```
<!-- android:installLocation="auto" -->

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name="AlarmReceiver"
        android:process=":remote" >
    </receiver>

    <activity
        android:name=".NotificationDialog"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Login"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SignUp"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Forecast"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Search"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Plot"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".PieChart"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.bargraph.BarGraph"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".BarGraph"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Reports"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Summary"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Calc"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Settings"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Accounts"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".AddAccount"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".EditAccount"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".FAQs"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SyncNRestore"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.dignizant.inappbilling.Plans"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Categories"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".AddCategory"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".EditSubCategories"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.wheel.main"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.horizontal.wheel.DefaultDateSlider"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    </activity>

    <service android:name="com.dignizant.inappbilling.BillingService" />

    <receiver android:name="com.dignizant.inappbilling.BillingReceiver" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.IN_APP_NOTIFY" />
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.RESPONSE_CODE" />
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Comment: When did u uploaded you app??

Comment: I don't know if this is causing that, but why do you list supported screen sizes?

Comment: @AkashG before six month but i updated it on 30th june

Comment: @stefan before update it was without list supported screen even thought it was not showing in the galaxy s3

Comment: are you sure that it is supposed to be listed? There are thousands of android devices out there and I imagine that not all of them are instantaneously in the list after launch to the market

Comment: my other uploaded application can see on galaxy s3 and i also make manifest same but still i cant see

Comment: Pls tally the changes u made with the code you uploaded before u made changes.

Comment: i tried to search it from device google play

Comment: i compared manifest file with the other code manifest file but there is no change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Googly play is using Filtering while user are searching app in Google play.

there are so many things to consider while search app in Google play.

Please visit the following link to getting idea.

[Filtering App in Google Play](http://hasmukhbhadani.blogspot.in/2013/01/filtering-app-in-google-play.html)

Let me know you have any Query!

Comment: your post really helped me to understand how to set manifest file for filtering app in googleplay